# What can i use to write this scala code better?

Tags: scala

```
functionThatReturnsATry[Boolean]() match {
      case Success(value) =>
        value match {
          case true => somethingThatReturnsFuture[Unit]
          case false =>
            Failure(new SomeException("This failed here"))
        }
      case Failure(exception) => Failure(exception)
    }
```

The code will return Future[Unit] when `functionThatReturnsATry` finishes succesfully and returns true.
If `functionThatReturnsATry` fails, i want to pass that failure up the chain.
If `functionThatReturnsATry` returns false, i want to pass a new sepecific failure up the chain

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One improvement would be to use guard expressions on the `match` to separate the three different cases. You should also return `Future.failed` rather than `Failure` so that the result is `Future[Unit]` not `Any`:

```
functionThatReturnsATry[Boolean]() match {
  case Success(value) if value =>
    somethingThatReturnsFuture[Unit]

  case Success(_) =>
    Future.failed(new SomeException("This failed here"))

  case Failure(exception) =>
    Future.failed(exception)
}
```

Comment: Or ```case Success(`true`) =>``` alternatively.

Comment: you can use `case Success(true) => ...`. This is keyword and it is matched by value.

Answer (score 3):

I like the existing answer, but as an alternative, if you don't care about controlling the precise exception of the first step, you can wrap your `Try` in a `Future` and use a `for`-comprehension:

```
def attempt(): Try[Boolean] = Success(true)
def soon(): Future[Unit] = Future.failed(new RuntimeException("uh"))

for {
  success <- Future.fromTry(attempt()) if success
  result <- soon()
} yield result
```

The code is available [here on Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/stefanobaghino/XGsqz5GbQoOexjBFDavAYg).

Answer (score 2):

I'd be tempted to `fold()` over the `Try`.

```
functionThatReturnsATryBool()
  .fold(Future.failed
       ,if (_) somethingThatReturnsFutureUnit()
        else Future.failed(new SomeException("This failed here"))
       )
```

The result is type `Future[Unit]` with either type of failure returned as `Future(Failure(java.lang.Exception(...)))`. No loss of error message.

Answer (score 2):

```scala
functionThatReturnsATry[Boolean]() match {
  case Success(true) => somethingThatReturnsFuture[Unit]
  case Success(false) => Future.failed(new SomeException("This failed here"))
  case Failure(exception) => Future.failed(exception)
}
```

https://scalafiddle.io/sf/DSaGvul/0